# Обобщенный интерфейс, ковариантность

Tags: c#, .net

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, по коду. Вот ради эксперимента набросал код, но не пойму, почему метод GetNameObj возвращает объект типа a1, если ему как через конструктор, так и через параметр типа передают a2. 
Вот код:

```
using System;
interface a<out T>
{
    T GetNameObj();
}
class b<T> : a<T>
{
    T t;
    public b(T o)
    {
        t = o;
    }
    public T GetNameObj()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
        return t;
    }
}
class a1 {  }
class a2 : a1 {  }
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a<a1> A = new b<a2>(new a2());
        a2 A2 =(a2) A.GetNameObj(); //вот этот метод почему-то возвращает тип a1

    }
}
```

Мне кажется, что единственным объяснением такого поведения является то, что методу без разницы, что я там передаю за тип данных в конструктор или параметр типа, ему главное, что в интерфейсной ссылке указан параметр типа a1. Но в таком случае приоритет выше у параметра типа интерфейса, чем у типа объекта? Или я что-то не правильно понял? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Код, который вы привели, возвращает a2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы встретились с различием между заявленным (compile-time) и реальным (run-time) типом.

Объект, создаваемый конструктором `new b<a2>(new a2())`, имеет реальный тип `b<a2>`.

Поскольку `b<T>` является разновидностью (то есть, подтипом) `a<T>` для любого `T`, то `b<a2>` есть разновидность `a<a2>`. Далее, `a2` есть подтип `a1`, поэтому, вследствие ковариантности `a<>`, `a<a2>` есть подтип `a<a1>`. Поэтому возможно присвоить переменной `A` типа `a<a1>` ссылку на объект типа `b<a2>`.

Далее, рассмотрим объект, возвращаемый `A.GetNameObj()`. Поскольку `A` имеет заявленный тип `a<a1>`, возвращённый объект имеет заявленный тип `a1`. Реальный же тип этого объекта — `a2`, т. к. реальный тип `A` — `b<a2>`.

При компиляции для присвоения переменной `A2` существенен лишь заявленный тип (компилятор в общем случае не знает, как будет реальный тип), поэтому код без приведения типов не скомпилируется. Тем не менее, приведение типов может привести объект к его реальному типу (но выяснится это лишь во время выполнения), поэтому код с приведением типов работает без выброса исключения.

---

По вашему вопросу:

> ...методу без разницы что я там передаю за тип данных в конструктор или параметр типа, ему главное что в интерфейсной ссылке указан параметр типа a1. Но в таком случае приоритет выше у параметра типа интерфейса чем у типа объекта ?

Для компилируемости кода важен лишь заявленный тип. В вашем случае важен заявленный тип переменной `A`, а не реальный тип объекта, который будет в эту переменную записан. Если бы вы заявили более сильный тип для переменной `A`, то приведение типов не понадобилось бы:

```
a<a2> A = new b<a2>(new a2());
a2 A2 = A.GetNameObj();
```